Discovery of magnetic properties in ancient Egypt
The use and study of magnetic rocks, as lodestones, is widely documented in antiquity, at least in China and Greece. I would like to know if similar discoveries are documented anywhere else and especially in ancient Egypt.  The problem with this topic is that it seems to be widely associated with what I would call "pseudo-science" theories and thus one can find a lot of misinformations. It is thus quite hard for me to find reliable references. Could someone help me?

The bone of Haroeri, which seems a splendid name for a lodestone! Trinity College Dublin is hopefully fairly reliable, though they give no references.

Thanks! Unfortunately I can not seem to find anything else about it :$

While I do not claim any expertise on the topic, I was curious and did some searching spurred by the comment from John Rennie to the OP. Searching for bone of Haroeri produces various variants (including that of Trinity College Dublin linked in the comment) of the following quote

The ancient Egyptians called the loadstone the bone of Haroeri, and iron the bone of Typhon. Haroeri was the son of Osiris and grandson of Rhea, a goddess of the earth, a queen of Atlantis, and mother of Poseidon; Typhon was a wind-god and an evil genius, but also a son of Rhea, the earth goddess.
I. L. Donnelly, Atlantis: The Antediluvian World (1882), p. 442 [pdf at Wikisource]

This might not be the most reliable source; according to Wikipedia this is a pseudoarchaeological book, and the source of many modern-day concepts about Atlantis :| Anyway, searching a little more, I learnt that

Heru-ur (or Herwer, and Haroeris to the Ptolemaic Greeks), also known as Horus the Elder, was a form of Horus [...]
Wikipedia, Horus, emphasis in the quote is mine.

It seems reasonable to assume that 'Haroeri' was (a either misprint or probably) a genitive of a Latinised version of 'Haroeris'. Happily, searching bone of Horus leads to the quote

Moreover, they call the loadstone the bone of Horus, and iron the bone of Typhon, as Manetho$^6$ records.
$^6$ Frag. 77.
Plutarch, Isis and Osiris, Ch. 62; F. C. Babbitt (transl.), Loeb Classical Library Vol L306, Plutarch Moralia V (New York, 1936), p. 147 [pdf at Internet Archive]

The reference is to Manetho's Aegyptiaca (History of Egypt), which is now largely lost, with parts surviving through other sources, like Plutarch above. Searching for the fragment, I came across the same quote of Plutarch, together with the following footnote

Interesting confirmation of the correctness of Plutarch and Manetho is given by G. A. Wainwright in his article "Iron in Egypt" (J. Hg. Arch. xviii. 1932, p. 14). He compares Pyramid Texts, § 14, "the bi$^)$ which came forth out of Setesh," and refers to Petrie's discovery at Kâw (an important centre of Sêth worship) of great quantities of gigantic bones, collected in piles: they were chiefly of hippopotami,—mineralized, heavy, black bones, of metallic lustre and appearance. It is clear that they were considered sacred to Sêth, as they were wrapped in linen and were found here and there in tombs at Kâw.
Manetho, Fr. 79; W. G. Waddell (transl.), W. Heinemann (London, 1940), p. 226 [pdf at Internet Archive]


Wonderful! thank you for digging all this! I guess that concluding from this that Egyptians had any knowledge of the magnetic properties of the lodestones seems quite a far stretch...
